# Error resolving imports (Typescript) (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I'm using jHipster to generate code. I have a simple import statement in my home.component.ts:

```
import { Account } from 'app/core/user/account.model'; //
        ///throws error - [ts] Cannot find module 'app/core/user/account.model'.
```

My app/core/user directory has the file account.model.ts, and it looks like so:

```
export class Account {
  constructor(
    public activated: boolean,
    public authorities: string[],
    public email: string,
    public firstName: string,
    public langKey: string,
    public lastName: string,
    public login: string,
    public imageUrl: string
  ) {}
}
```

Why am I getting this error if the file is existing?

(note: Angular CLI: 10.0.0
Node: 12.18.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 10.0.0
jHipster: 6.10.3)

Comment: I was able to get the error to go away if I put the fully qualified file (e.g. C:/Users/...) but how can I have angular remember this directory (i.e. prefix the file)?

Comment: Have you tried specifying it as a relative path?

Comment: I have to specify the path all the way up to C:/Users/ in order to resolve imports, and when I replace with '..' (which I think is what you mean by relative) then it doesn't resolve the import.

Comment: Mind if we take a look at your tsconfig.json? There should be baseDir and paths defined there.

Comment: see [TypeScript: Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

Comment: In other words, relative paths start with `/`, `.`, or `..`, and absolute paths are generally for node modules. You do not tell use where `home.component.ts` is, so there is no way to give you how to use a relative import for `account.model.ts`.